# Scroll view cant scroll all the way to the end

Tags: unity-game-engine

So im having this problem in unity where im trying to create a Scroll View but i don't know why, when press the play button and go to the scroll view, it wont let me scroll. It tries to scroll but it always gets back to its original position. I've tried to see other posts and they talk about using the content size filter but even then its still happening. Here are some captures of the scroll view.

This is the scroll view

[Scroll View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYFTm.png)

[Scroll View component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWE6i.png)

This is the viewport

[View Port component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeUIo.png)

And this is the content

[Content component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Dil.png)

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? It would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. Seems like i needed to add a vertical layout group.